# Strong RSA problem in $\mathbb Z^*_{n^2}$

Tags: rsa

Comparing to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6456/how-hard-are-discrete-logarithms-problems-in-mathbb-z-n-and-mathbb-z), assume $C, M \in \mathbb Z^*_{n^2}$, $e \ge 3$, is it hard to compute $M$ that satisfies $C=M^e \mod n^2$ when $C$ and $(n, e)$ are given?

Comment: Hint: $C=M^e \bmod n^2\implies C\equiv M^e \pmod n$.